# How do I check if Native Host was installed?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, native, messaging, host

I am developing a Google Chrome extension that uses Native Messaging.
In some tests *(with the native host already manually installed before)* I have successfully connected with it and executed everything I needed. Everything was fine.
I need to download and send messages to the host as soon as it is installed.
I can download it automatically when the extension is installed.

```
var downloadItem = function(){
  chrome.downloads.download({
      url: "http://example.net/downloads/host.exe"
    }, insertContentScripts);
}

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(downloadItem);
```

After the download starts the content scripts are injected on specific tabs.

```
var insertContentScripts = 
    chrome.windows.getAll({
        populate: true
    }, function (windows) {
        var i = 0, w = windows.length, currentWindow;
        for ( ; i < w; i++ ) {
            currentWindow = windows[i];
            var j = 0, t = currentWindow.tabs.length, currentTab;
            for ( ; j < t; j++ ) {
                currentTab = currentWindow.tabs[j];
                // load just on example.com pages
                if (currentTab.url.match(regex)) {
                    injectIntoTab(currentTab);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

var injectIntoTab = function (tab) {
        // You could iterate through the content scripts here
        var scripts = chrome.manifest.content_scripts[0].js;
        var i = 0, s = scripts.length;
        for( ; i < s; i++ ) {
            console.debug("Inserting script '" + scripts[i] + "' to tab " + tab.url);
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
                file: scripts[i]
            });
        }   
    }
```

How can I check when the host is installed, and then connect with it?

Comment: Simply try to connect periodically: it'll return an error or undefined when the app is not installed.

Comment: @wOxxOm I have actually tried that with a `while(true)`, but it crashes chrome =/

Comment: `while(true)` is never a solution. "Periodically" means setInterval or setTimeout.

Comment: @wOxxOm I am trying to connect periodically using setTimeout(), but chrome it is still crashing

Comment: Sorry, wrong typing, edited the comment

Comment: Try enabling logging: https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @wOxxOm I could solve the problem.
The solution was when the content scripts are injected, the page sends messages to the `background.js` script to try to connect to the native app **periodically**.
This way, whenever it doesn't returns an error, it means that the host was installed. 
The final script looks like this:

***content.js***

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({funcao: "testExtension"}, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

***background.js***

```
if (request.funcao == "testExtension"){
    var timerId = 0;
    timerId = setInterval(function () {
      message(timerId);
    }, 1000);
}
```

***message(id) function***

```
function message(timerId){
  var success = false;
  chrome.runtime.sendNativeMessage('com.pany.app', {"funcao": "testExtension"},
        function(response) {    
          if (typeof chrome.runtime.lastError === "undefined" || chrome.runtime.lastError.message.indexOf("not found") === -1) {
            success = true;
          }
      });
  if(success){
    clearInterval(timerId);
  }
}
```